# Add embedded image to an email with TIdAttachmentFile

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

My problem is that I added an embedded image to an email using `TIdAttachmentFile`, so far it has worked with Outlook as I want, but not with Gmail.

The image is added and Outlook appears correct, but in Gmail it appears as an attachment and I want it to be part of the body of the email.

An important fact is that the image to add is gotten encoded in base64, but that's not the problem.

This is my current code:

```
Msg := TIdMessage.Create;
Msg.Subject := 'Testing';
Msg.FromList.AddItems(fromList);
Msg.Recipients.AddItems(recipientList);
Msg.Body.Clear;
Msg.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';

htmlBody := TStringList.Create;
htmlBody.Add('<p>Sending an image</p>');
htmlBody.Add('<img src="cid:' + cid + '" /></p>');

bodyPart := TIdText.Create(Msg.MessageParts, htmlBody);
bodyPart.ContentType := 'text/html';

  crypt := Tcrypt.Create;
  imgBytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imgB64);
  imgBytes := crypt.Base64DecodeBytes(imgBytes);

  imgPart := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Msg.MessageParts);
  imgPart.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  imgPart.ContentDisposition := 'inline';
  imgPart.ContentID := cid;
  imgPart.FileName := cid;
  imgPart.LoadFromStream(TBytesStream.Create(imgBytes));

if sendEmail(Msg, s) then //Function that sends the email
  Result := '{"status":true}'
else
  Result := '{"msg":"' + s + '"}';
```

The following code is for the function that is called at the end, configures the SMTP and sends the email:

```
function TFunciones.sendEmail(Msg: TIdMessage; out outMsgError : String) : Boolean;
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
begin
  outMsgError := '';
  SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);

  try
    SMTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(SMTP);
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(SMTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SMTP.AuthType := TIdSMTPAuthenticationType.satDefault;

    SMTP.Host := SMTP_HOST;
    SMTP.Port := SMTP_PORT;
    SMTP.Username := SMTP_USERNAME;
    SMTP.Password := SMTP_PASSWORD;

    SMTP.Connect;
    SMTP.Send(Msg);
    SMTP.Disconnect;
    Result := True;
  Except
    on E : Exception do begin
      Result := False;
      outMsgError := E.Message;
    end;
  end;

  SMTP.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Given the structure of your email, you need to set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` to `'multipart/related; type="text/html"'` instead of `'multipart/mixed'`. See [HTML Messages](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.aspx) on Indy's website. Also, you might consider using `TIdAttachmentMemory` instead of `TIdAttachmentFile`, or even write a custom `TIdAttachment` class to wrap your `TBytes` directly so you dont have to make a copy of it. Also, this code has some memory leaks if it is run on desktop platforms.

Comment: Also, when setting up the `SSLIOHandler`, you should not be using `SSLOptions.Method` let alone `sslvSSLv23`. Use `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` instead, and enable only the `sslvTLSv...` flags and none of the `sslvSSLv...` flags